# Removing HTML from CSV file data with PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have a nasty CSV file with 10,000 rows that I am reading with `fgetcsv()` and then inserting the data into a MySQL database. The CSV data includes HTML tags, double quotes and commas. Here's an example:

```
<div id=\"stcpDiv\">Maecenas eget blandit turpis. Cras lectus orci, 
rutrum et risus a, egestas eleifend lorem. \"Morbi eu mi\" consequat, 
elementum diam sit amet, maximus eros. Quisque imperdiet finibus 
tellus, eu eleifend tortor porta non. Nulla feugiat tellus tempus, 
pharetra mauris ut, <pre>laoreet nunc</pre>. Proin vulputate arcu 
augue, \"et maximus\" sem faucibus nec. Aliquam vel diam enim. Ut 
fringilla auctor vulputate. Vestibulum tincidunt felis ac enim 
elementum, dapibus malesuada orci rutrum.</div>
<div></div>
```

I am opening the file like this:

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ',', '"')) !== false) {
```

The file is saved with double quotes around the data and with a comma as the delimiter.

I have two questions:

First, how do I clean up this data, removing the HTMl and quotes so it can go into the database correctly? I have tried `strip_tags()` with no luck. I have tried using `str_replace()` to replace the double quotes and `stripslashes()` to delete those "\"-characters with no luck. I just get broken data.

Second, is there a way to do this and maintain line breaks?

Here's my full code:

```
function display_import_tool() {

     global $wpdb;

     if ($_POST) {

        $import_file = "/import/import.csv";

        $file = fopen($import_file, "r");

        $rows = array();
        while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ',', '"')) !== false) {
            $rows[] = $line;
        }

        fclose($file);

        $count = count($rows);

        if ($count > 0) {
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                $content = array();
                $content['id'] = $row[0];
                $content['first_name'] = $row[1];
                $content['middle_name'] = $row[2];
                $content['last_name'] = $row[3];

                $content['main_text'] = $row[4];

                $wpdb->insert("fgss_users", $content);
            }

        }
     }
```

Comment: `strip_tags()` and `stripslashes()` are the functions for such a job. What do you mean with “I just get broken data”?

Comment: please provide more actual code, so we can see what you're currently doing.

Comment: I added some code above. I need to clean up that text. Strip out the HTML, avoid comma conflicts ad if possible maintain new lines.

Comment: **Just a note:** a full code can't be considered a full code if you're missing a `}`.

Comment: If you're inserting HTML into the database you might want to take a look at [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).